# VK api SDK установка и подключение, как правильно?

Tags: php, php-vksdk

Не получается вникнуть в суть... Сегодня первый раз в жизни с git установил что-то на сайт через терминал...
Решил полюбопытствовать как устроена VK api SDK, но даже подключить не получилось )))) Не пойму, уже кучу вариантов попробовал, не получается запустить...

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$vk = new \VK\Client\VKApiClient('5.92');

$oauth = new \VK\OAuth\VKOAuth(); 
$client_id = API_CLIENT_ID; 
$redirect_uri = 'http://site.ru/index.php'; 
$display = VKOAuthDisplay::PAGE; 
$scope = array(VKOAuthUserScope::WALL, VKOAuthUserScope::GROUPS); 
$state = 'secret_state_code'; 

$browser_url = $oauth->getAuthorizeUrl(VKOAuthResponseType::CODE, $client_id, $redirect_uri, $display, $scope, $state);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VKOAuthDisplay' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причины в том, что Вы пытаетесь использовать классы, которые находятся не в одном пространстве имён с текущим сценарием. Используйте `use` , либо пишите все пути полностью, например:

```
$display = \VK\OAuth\VKOAuthDisplay::PAGE;
```

Этот самый путь можно узнать в самом классе, который вызывается. Он следует после слова namespace. Приведённый вариант подразумевает указание путей в начале класса при помощи `use`. Но можно указывать как в примере выше.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я уже расстроился и снес эту приколюху ))
Но после вашего ответа, установил и все получилось )
Теперь вопрос, это же не очень удобно) Жить можно конечно, но сколько лишних символов в коде будет...

Answer (score 0):

Кому нужно, вот что получилось... Спасибо Eddir!

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; 

use \VK\Client\VKApiClient;
use \VK\OAuth\VKOAuth;
use \VK\OAuth\VKOAuthDisplay;
use \VK\OAuth\Scopes\VKOAuthUserScope;
use \VK\OAuth\VKOAuthResponseType;

$vk = new VKApiClient(VER);

$oauth = new VKOAuth(); 
$client_id = API_CLIENT_ID; 
$redirect_uri = REDIR; 
$display = VKOAuthDisplay::PAGE; 
$scope = array(VKOAuthUserScope::WALL, VKOAuthUserScope::GROUPS); 
$state = 'secret_state_code'; 

$browser_url = $oauth->getAuthorizeUrl(VKOAuthResponseType::CODE, $client_id, $redirect_uri, $display, $scope, $state);

print $browser_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Для удобства можно использовать довольно шуструю либу  https://github.com/ctapu4ok/vk-messenger-sdk

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
}

use ctapu4ok\VkMessengerSdk\EventHandler;
use ctapu4ok\VkMessengerSdk\Logger;
use ctapu4ok\VkMessengerSdk\Settings;
use ctapu4ok\VkMessengerSdk\Attributes\Cron;

enum Params
{
    public const API_HASH = 'vk1.a.GLlGmwNDe1iuRj....';
    public const GROUP_ID = 12345678;
    public const CONFIRM_STRING = 'c683e9eb12cebb65ce323467d8ab32508e55c7a0ecfecc0a0e92e31d8785adf4';

    public const VERSION = '5.81';
}

class MessengerEvent extends EventHandler
{
    public function messageNew(int $group_id, ?string $secret, array $object): void
    {
        $this->wrapper->getAPI()->logger([
            'New message received: ', $object
        ], Logger::LOGGER_CALLABLE);

        /**
         * @var $this->wrapper Main wrapper
         * @var $this->wrapper->getAPI()->vk The main VK API methods src/API/Actions
         */
        $msg_id = $this->wrapper->getAPI()->vk->messages()->send([
            'user_id' => $object['message']['from_id'],
            'random_id' => floor(microtime(true) * 1000),
            'peer_id' => $object['message']['peer_id'],
            'message' => 'Hello World!'
        ]);

        $this->wrapper->getAPI()->logger([
            'Getting Message ID: ', $msg_id
        ], Logger::LOGGER_CALLABLE);
    }

    public function messageTypingState(int $group_id, ?string $secret, array $object): void
    {
        $this->wrapper->getAPI()->logger([
            'The user started typing a message', $object
        ], Logger::LOGGER_CALLABLE);
    }

    #[Cron(period: 5)]
    public function testingCron5()
    {
        $this->wrapper->getAPI()->logger([
            'THIS IS CRON 5!!!!!!'
        ], Logger::LOGGER_CALLABLE);
    }

    #[Cron(period: 1)]
    public function testingSome1()
    {
        $this->wrapper->getAPI()->logger([
            'THIS IS CRON 1.0!!!!!!'
        ], Logger::LOGGER_CALLABLE);
    }
}

function extracted(): void
{
    $Settings = new Settings();

    $Settings->getAppInfo()->setApiHash(Params::API_HASH);
    $Settings->getAppInfo()->setGroupId(Params::GROUP_ID);
    $Settings->getAppInfo()->setConfirmString(Params::CONFIRM_STRING);
    $Settings->getAppInfo()->setApiVersion(Params::VERSION);

    MessengerEvent::loop($Settings);
}

extracted();
```